# SQL Server Management Studio - Tabbed Documents

Tags: sql, ssms

I am working in SQL Server Management Studio.  I can no longer see more than one tab at a time.

If I have a script open and start a new query, SSMS closes my open script.

If I open from file and select multiple scripts; it opens the first, closes it and opens the next, repeatedly until only the final file selected is open.

This began yesterday after I played with the dock settings of my query screen.

Comment: I've never heard of anything like that before.  What version of SSMS are you using?

Comment: did you try the evergreen shutdown the computer and restart?

Comment: I am working with SQL Server 2012.  I am a bit of a noob; but I don't think I have made any type of change that should have caused this.

Comment: I have shutdown and restarted several times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've probably (somehow) ended up with "Reuse current document window, if saved" ticked, as below:

[image]

From Tools->Options, Top option on right hand side.

Untick it.

Comment: I knew there was something in the Options but couldn't find it because looked in the wrong place.

Comment: I am a bit embarrassed but also unsurprised.  Thank You Damien_The_Unbeliever, RBarry and Paolo.