# SQL Studio 2012 - Every time I open a tab, it closes whatever was open just before

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

For the past weeks, when I have a tab open in SQL Server Management Studio and I want to open another tab (multi-tab) by either right clicking on a table or trying to open a file, it simply closes my existing tab and opens the new one.

I can right click on a table, -> Script Table As -> New Query Editor Window and it will always override the current tab.

Example:

- First attempt, opens SQLQuery1.sql
- I can try to open the same table or a different table and it overrides the tab mentioned above with SQLQuery2.sql, and so on
- Can't get to work with Multiple tabs
- Has been working for years

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Forgive me for being new here and not knowing if I should be posting an answer when a question has already been answered somewhere else. @TheMig, I think your question was answered here:
[SQL Server Management Studio - Tabbed Documents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26238487/sql-server-management-studio-tabbed-documents#26238710)